# How to check last updated value in the DB with ef and c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, timestamp

I have a sql server DB which contains a table. I am accessing the data through ef. The table contains a  "timestamp" column. I would like to query the table by the timestamp in order to find the last modified item and show the user the date and time of this modification.

How to do it?

Comment: Do you have a column in the table with the last_modified datetime in it? A timestamp column cannot be converted to a datetime http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: I am working on someone elses DB which I can not change. I was hoping to be able to get the modification date from the property. Thanx

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = this.context.YourEntity
               .OrderByDescending(gt=> gt.TimeStamp)
               .FirstOrDefault();
```